# read_feather over network drive slow

Tags: r, feather

I have a data.frame of moderate size, and I tested storing and retrieving it to a network drive using both `rds` (uncompressed) and `feather` format. But the result shows that while `write_feather` is much faster than `saveRDS`, `read_feather` is much slower than `readRDS`.

Question(s). Does this have something to do with the particular network configuration of my workplace (i.e. is it just me)? or does it have something to do with the innate ability to handle remote files of `read_feather` and `readRDS`? Shall I stick to `rds` for now?

```
> print(object.size(impdata),unit="auto")
364.4 Mb

## SAVING
> system.time(feather::write_feather(impData,path="M:/waangData/test.feather"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.52    0.16    4.80 
> system.time(saveRDS(impData,file="M:/waangData/Data4predictImp.rds",compress=F))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.23    2.35   28.61 

## READING
> system.time({t2=feather::read_feather("M:/waangData/test.feather")})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.59    1.54  134.39 
> system.time({t=readRDS("M:/waangData/Data4predictImp.rds")})
   user  system elapsed 
   2.36    0.61   19.59
```

Comment: why dont you time it using local copies of those files first? then any unexplained timings will be due to the network. when network is slow, your file sizes should be as small as possible. you might also want to check out `fst` package as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have clarified the question. No doubt the fact that the file is remote is slowing down things. My question is really, is it some innate design limitation of `read_feather` that makes it slower than `readRDS` when it comes to reading remote files.

Comment: @qoheleth I have noticed this too. Reading `feather` objects into R is quite slow even when reading it locally, with sizes of 10-15MB. Have you found any solutions or reasons why this is?